# How to shift the contents of a memory location left 1 bit to another memory using z80 assembly language

Tags: assembly, bit-shift, microprocessors, z80

Example , left shifting 1 bit from location 1900H and store in location 1901H , and empty bit positions are filled with zero

Answer (score 3):

Home work?

Not 100% sure if this is what you're asking for, but anyway:

```
...
    XOR A          ; clear Carry
    LD A,(1900H)
    RLA            ; left shift, bit 7 goes to Carry, bit 0 filled with 0
    LD (1900H),A   ; save shifted value
    LD A,(1901H)
    RLA            ; left shift, bit 0 filled with bit 7 of the original (1900h)
    LD (1901H),A   ; save shifted value
    ...
```

*There are, of course, other ways to achieve the same*.

Added another one from the comment:

```
LD HL,(1900H)   ; load 16-bit value: L<-(1900H), H<-(1901H)
ADD HL,HL       ; HL <- HL+HL = HL*2 - equivalent of left shift by 1 bit
LD (1900H),HL   ; save to the same location
```

The above snippet is 7 bytes in size and, probably, the shortest possible code for the task.

Comment: Can you avoid `XOR A` by adding the accumulator to itself instead of the first `RLA`?  `x += x` is equivalent to a left-shift by 1 (shifting in a zero) and when done with an add instruction, should put the carry out into the carry flag.  I don't know much Z80 but I assume it has an A+=A instruction.

Comment: Or can you load the 2 adjacent bytes into a 16-bit register pair and do a 16-bit add?  Like HL+=HL?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes to both. The 2nd option is probably the shortest possible: LD HL,(1900H); ADD HL,HL; LD (1900H),HL - 7 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the simpler case of shifting one byte left, and
shifting in a 0-bit. On the Z80, this perfectly describe the
`sla` set of instructions:

```
    sla [reg8]
```

Where `reg8` is one of the registers A/B/C/D/E/H/L, or (HL), or (IX+d)
or (IY+d). The top bit gets shifted out of the register (or
memory location in the case of (HL)/(IX+d)/(IY+d)) and into the
carry flag.

There is a well known trick for 4 special cases on the Z80.
Since shifting left (while shifting in a 0) is the same as
multiplying by 2, you can actually simulate an `sla` with:

```
    add a,a     ; replaces `sla a`, save 1 byte, 4cc
    add hl,hl   ; replaces `sla l \ rl h`, save 3 bytes, 5cc
    add ix,ix   ; (to my knowedge, this is the only "legal" way to shift the IX register pair like this)
    add iy,iy   ; (same with IY)
```

These are faster and smaller and almost always the best
replacement.

In any event, the bit that was shifted out is now in the carry
flag, so you can shift that into the next byte using the `rl`
class of instructions:

```
    rl [reg8] ;2 bytes,  8 clock cycles
    rla       ;1b, 4cc. Basically a fast `rl a` but affects fewer flags.
```

Notice that the Z80 has an optimized ersion of this specifically
for the A register.

---

Now on to your question: There are many ways to do this on the
Z80. If you know precisely where in memory the bytes are, @tum_
provided the fastests and smallest option:

```
    ld hl,(1900H) ; Read the two bytes into HL
    add hl,hl     ; Shift left
    ld (1900H),hl ; Store HL back to the bytes.
```

This takes advantage of the `sla` trick from earlier, where you
can just add HL to itself (HL*2) to shift it left. However, if
the bytes are not at a pre-determined location, but HL points to
the bytes, then:

```
    sla (hl)  ; `sla` the byte at HL
    inc hl    ; Advance to the next byte
    rl (hl)   ; `rl` the byte at HL
```

You can also do it a little slower (not recommened, just showing
this for educational purposes):

```
    ld a,(hl) ; read the byte at HL into A
    add a,a   ; `sla a`, but faster and smaller
    ld (hl),a ; Store it back to the byte at HL
    inc hl    ; advance to the next byte
    ld a,(hl) ; read the byte at HL into A
    rla       ; `rl a`, but faster and smaller
    ld (hl),a ; Store it back to the byte at HL
```

---

This is a lot of info, but hopefully this helps!